# Checking whether ENTRYPOINT is set in previous docker layer

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Assume I have the following Docker image (let's call it **sample-imagev1**):

```
FROM python:latest

RUN echo Doing stuff
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install # So on so forth

ENTRYPOINT ["/sample-image/super-duper-starter"]
```

Now let's assume I create a new image, based on **sample-imagev1** (for reference lets call it **sample-imagev2**) which looks like this:

```
FROM sample-image:v1

RUN echo "hello!"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python # ... So on so forth
```

## What I'm trying to do

Is it possible to detemine in **sample-imagev2**'s Dockerfile, whether ENTRYPOINT has been set in **sample-imagev1**?
i.e, something like

```
RUN echo THE PREVIOUS ENTRYPOINT IS: $ENTRYPOINT
```

That would be cool, wouldn't it?

## What I've thought of

Well, If I need to guess what the ENTRYPOINT instruction is doing - it probably saves the value you provided in some kind of special docker header in the image. This header is aggregated on each layer you add so if one runs ENTRYPOINT again (i.e in sample-imagev2) it just overrides this property.

**Bottom line:** Is it possible to determine such a thing solely from the Dockerfile itself?

Comment: From outside the image, you can see the commands used to create the image using `docker history <image>`. Docker images always build on top of each other, so if you override the entrypoint, there will be two entrypoint layers with the last one as the 'winner' that gets run.

Comment: `docker inspect` on the base image will also tell you what its configured `ENTRYPOINT` is, if any.  If you're unclear you can always set it directly in the derived image.

Answer (score 1):

From inside of the Dockerfile, during the build, there is currently no way to detect the previous settings of fields like ENTRYPOINT, CMD, or LABEL.

With buildkit, it's possible to change the Dockerfile parser with a syntax line, and using that you may be able to create a frontend that adds this functionality, but it would be buildkit specific, and if the feature isn't accepted upstream, you would have to maintain it yourself.

Typically, people use base images that they know and trust, and would be aware of the settings of the base image they've selected in the Dockerfile. And if functionality like a custom entrypoint is needed, they often maintain customized base images with that enhancement.